# New outlet doesn't fit because the Mirror wall hole is offset from drywall which is offset from junction box

Tags: electrical, drywall, receptacle, mirror

A bit of a head scratcher...

Just bought a home, and found that an outlet on the mirror was ungrounded. So I thought I would take a look, and I found a nice surprise after taking the outlet [image: off]

as you can see, the hole in the mirror is offset from the drywall, which is offset from the junction box. Also there are no ground wires.

a professional electrician recommended an AFGF outlet, which I bought, but it's bigger than a normal outlet, and will not fit the same way the old outlet (barely) fit. The junction box is big enough, but because it is offset, the outlet won't fit in the exposed opening of the box.

There is a stud on the left, and the junction box is nailed in with a little metal wing sticking out on the top left side of the box

So the way I see it, there are only two options that don't require breaking the mirror

1. Somehow take out the existing junction box, and install a new one higher. Cut the drywall hole to match the mirror. Somehow attach junction box to the stud
2. Cut a circle shape out of another mirror and attach it too the top. Then cut the mirror at the bottom to expose the rest of the existing junction box

Best resulting job would be option 3, which is take out the entire mirror wall and install a new one... but that seems not worth it. Also there is access behind it, it is a floor-to-ceiling closet shelving system. So to access the junction box from the back would require cutting a hole in wood shelving, and the drywall behind that

I'm leaning towards removing the nail, dropping the junction box down, cutting the drywall, inserting a new junction box, and somehow attaching it to the stud, maybe with a 90 degree attachment on my power drill w/ a screw? space is very tight though. Looking for any ideas at all

Comment: Will not be easy or fun but unless that is a load bearing wall, can try notching the stud so the box can move over some also.

Comment: interesting idea! that would help move it left, but it still needs more vertical space too

Comment: Would make the notch to fit the hole in the mirror.  A 1/2 or 3/4 inch notch should be okay in a plain wall, quite iffy in a load bearing wall.  Place the notch where you want it, up/down to match.  A small back saw or a jig saw plus a chisel should work.

Comment: i can definitely pull that off! but there would still be the problem of moving the junction box, because that thing is nailed too low

Comment: I have pulled mirrors like those off the wall with suction cups. Some have been as large as 7' x4'...took 2 of us but they came off intact.  Then you can reposition the box and reinstall the mirror with mirror adhesive.

Comment: With replacing the box, do not need to be that careful with the box.  If you can bang a hammer/prybar behind the nail/lip it should come off.  Might not be pretty after.

Comment: Is the stud to the left or right of it?  Note that the box also needs to come to the surface of the mirror, or be centered well enough for an extension sleeve to work.  It can't be 1/2" down in the wall.

Comment: The power that comes to this box... Where does it come *from*?  Straight from the panel, or from a nearby light switch or outlet elsewhere?

Comment: You've got a metal box. You *might* have ground to the *outside* of that box even though you can't see a ground wire right now - I have quite a few boxes like that in my house. Check for continuity/low resistance between neutral and the metal box - if you have that then you've almost certainly got ground. Still need to solve the physical issues but you could then use a self-grounding receptacle and you're done.

Comment: thanks for all the comments folks!

@RMDman i have no idea how the mirror is mounted on the wall, but i see caulk, and also once it becomes a two-person job, i'm not sure how i would find anyone to help

Comment: @crip659 yeah i think I found I'll be able to take the current box out easily, but then i'm not sure how to get a new box in there, and mount it to the stud without any space. is there a box that can be mounted from the inside of the box?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, the power comes from another outlet, there are about 5 outlets chained in a series, to the panel. this one in particular is like the 3rd outlet down. The stud is also to the left of it

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I tested it and didn't find ground, i think they literally just nailed a metal box onto the wooden stud, unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Don't even put a GFCI here

Believe it or not, GFCIs don't just protect their own sockets.

I mean, we'd hope so, since GFCIs are also available as circuit breakers and deadfronts, and *they don't even have sockets*, so clearly, GFCIs have a way to protect other things wired to them.

Indeed they do, and that is a pair of special terminals called "LOAD" carefully concealed so only pro electricians can find them - oh wait, I am not king, so they  put them in plain sight where they confuse the hell out of people.

No, all wires should be attached to the LINE terminals.  They take 2 wires; read the instructions for how.  Now, if you *actively want to* use that GFCI to protect other locations downline, then *and only then* attach those hot and neutral wires on the LOAD terminals.

Got it?

But only do that if you're willing to comply with the labeling requirement in instructions 8(c) and 406.4(D)(2).

### Put the GFCI before. Use LOAD to protect this outlet.

Now this removes the challenge of fitting a GFCI in this location.

You will need "GFCI Protected" markings on this and every receptacle now protected.

Comment: thanks for your time! that makes a lot of sense to me. i actually had this idea from a previous electrician, because he said if i really wanted to be as safe as possible without ground, that i should also have an Arc Fault protection (AF/GF), and as far as i understood it, AF does not protect down the load, it only protects the single outlet? though i'm not exactly sure what arc fault would protect against, and how it differs from GF

Comment: @AO -- arc fault protection can and *does* protect downline loads

Comment: @AO Almost everywhere arc fault protection is required, it's required to be *at the breaker* so it protects both appliances and wiring.  That even applied to the original use-case, which was electric blankets in bedrooms.  But of course that showed the value of protecting wiring. I'm not aware of any protection technology that works best at the receptacle (though it certainly is more convenient for the person trying to find the reset switch lol).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I never expected to see a home renovation job where a dremel was the best tool, +1 for proving me wrong.  I see no other way to cut the nails that hold the electrical box on the wrong position.

first you want to pack some wood into the box and drill through the wood to prepare screw holes in the box for fixing it in its new location,  the wood will make it possible to drill through the sheet metal on an angle.

you want three holes 2 near the front and one near the back, you will need a long bit for the back hole.

cut the upper drywall out of the way. Then you hook a long wire onto the top screw hole, more about this wire later.

Then reach in there an cut through the nails that are holding the box in its position.

push the box sideways off the nail stubs and clean up the top nail stub.
you're probably going to want to pull it out, locking pliers can help here,
be careful to not hit the mirror.

If the box dissappears inside the wall pull on the long wire.

Wrestle the box into its new position and nail or screw it to the stud.
if you're prone to missing with a hammer screw it into position.

If you need to move the box sideways you'll be doing some chiselling,
althrough you may be able to move most of the wood with a drill.
Make sure your chisels are sharp. and don't miss.

Comment: actually this is an amazing idea. I will try this first actually! will report back

Comment: this is going to work best if the wires come into the top of the box,  if the come in the bottom they may be too short.

Comment: they do indeed come from the top of the box. i'm going to go to the store and buy a new plastic box, the tricky part will be to swap out the boxes with just that tiny hole to work with